# Unable to attach gdb to remote process using pwntools

Tags: gdb, pwntools

I was playing with pwntools. I can connect to gdb to local process.

```
p = process()
gdb.attach(p)
```

Like this. But if I wanna attach gdb to a remote process it throws error.

```
p = remote(ip, port)
gdb.attach(p)
```

It throws this error:

```
[ERROR] Could not find remote process (10.10.207.165:9002) on this machine
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pegasus/Documents/tryhackme_pwn/challenge2/exploit2.py", line 19, in <module>
    gdb.attach(p, '''
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pwnlib/context/__init__.py", line 1578, in setter
    return function(*a, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pwnlib/gdb.py", line 926, in attach
    log.error('Could not find remote process (%s:%d) on this machine' %
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pwnlib/log.py", line 439, in error
    raise PwnlibException(message % args)
pwnlib.exception.PwnlibException: Could not find remote process (10.10.207.165:9002) on this machine
[*] Closed connection to 10.10.207.165 port 9002
```

How can I fix it? I think pwntools now supports connecting gdb directly to remote objects.

Comment: And you have a remote process that listens on port 9002?